# how to check if an array has colums in a schema?

Tags: apache-spark, schema, azure-databricks

I have a schema and I would like to check the array if it has columns inside before exploding it. my schema looks like this

```
 |-- CaseNumber: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Interactions: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- EmailInteractions: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- CreatedBy: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- CreatedOn: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Direction: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- PhoneInteractions: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- WebInteractions: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- EntityAction: string (nullable = true)
```

I would like to check if "EmailInteractions" has elements under it before I run the job that will explode it,

I have edited the question for clarity

```
1. check if email interactions array exist and check if it has columns, if both true, explode the array and finish, if one of the conditions is false, pass to step 2

2.check if phone interactions array exist and check if it has columns, if both true, explode the array and finish, if one of the conditions is false, pass to step 3

3.check if web interactions exist and check if it has columns, if both true, explode the array and finish, if one of the conditions is false, finish
```

I am new to coding and data bricks, please help on this.

Comment: how about checking array size, does that gives any information ?

Comment: @Yonas did you try my answer?

Answer (score -1):

This is one way of doing it. Unfortunately information under `StructField` is not searchable easily, I converted it to a string and search the filed by field name or keyword "StructField" to know that it contains a field.

```
    val jsonWithNull = """{"a": 123,"b":null,"EmailInteractions":[{"CreatedBy":"test"}]}"""
    val jsonWithoutNull = """{"a": 123,"b":3,"EmailInteractions":[{"CreatedBy":"test1"}]}"""

    import spark.implicits._
    val df = spark.read.json(Seq(jsonWithNull,jsonWithoutNull).toDS)
    df.printSchema()

    val field = df.schema.filter { f =>
      if (f.dataType.typeName == "array" && f.toString().contains("CreatedBy")){
        true
      }
      else{
        false
      }
    }

    println(field)

// check for field value being not null then explode
```

Result `List(StructField(EmailInteractions,ArrayType(StructType(StructField(CreatedBy,StringType,true)),true),true))`

Comment: Hi Salim, sorry I was OOF, I will test and let you know, thanks

Comment: Hi Salim, I have edited the question for clarity, please see on top and help on that. I really appreciate the help. thanks